# Run a dynamic number of threads with value return in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, dynamic, return-value

So basically I'm trying to implement a Genetic Algorithm, but the part that worries me is optimization. I'm trying to make a Class that checks the fitness of each node, however I'd like to run simultaneous checks because the data won't be altered in the checking process, and is the same for each thread. What I've come up to is this:

```
// check the gene for overlaps in room reservation
    for (int i=0;i<nrRooms;i++){
    FitnessThread thread = new FitnessThread(chromosome);
    }
```

With the thread's run function executing the checking code and filling an integer with the number of violations, to shorten it up:

```
for(int j=0; j<individualLength; j++){
                if(chromosome.getGene((offset*individualLength)+j) * 
                    chromosome.getGene((offsetNext*individualLength)+j) != 0){
                    violations++;
                }
            }
```

My question is, how can I collect the violations from each individual thread without ending up in a linear process. Can I just declare an array of threads and then start them at the same time, and collect from each individually once they've executed? Or is there some other method?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create `Callable`s and submit them to an executor pool, then use `Future.get();` to retrieve their results.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4); // or another kind of executor
List<Future<Foo>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0;i < nrRooms; i++) {
    futures.add(executor.submit(new FitnessCallable(chromosome)));
}
...
// Time to check the results
for(Future<Foo> f : futures) {
    Foo result = f.get();  // Block and get the result
}
```

Comment: A very good answer. Could you please make it a little more explicit (a sample code would be nice)? I think it could help quite a lot of people.

Comment: For examples kindly refer this [link](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html).

Comment: Yes please, I've never used Callable before and after some research I'm still confused how I could retrieve multiple values from multiple callables. Does the future.get() method combine the values or returns an array?

Comment: @Flopn It returns a single value from a single `Callable` of course. The type of the value is decided by you.

Comment: This worked exactly as I needed it to with a few tweaks, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 you can do

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Chromosome> chromosomes = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Pair<Double, Chromosome>> sortedByFitness 
                = chromosomes.parallelStream()
                .map(c -> Pair.of(c.finess(), c))
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(p -> p.l).reversed())
                .limit(100) // best 100 values.
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}

class Pair<L, R>{
    L l;
    R r;

    public Pair(L l, R r) {
        this.l = l;
        this.r = r;
    }

    public static <L, R> Pair<L, R> of(L l, R r) {
        return new Pair<>(l, r);
    }
}
```